# virtual box installation failing on ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, docker-machine

I have tried to create docker machines on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)
with the following command:

```
docker-machine create test.com
```

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is \"WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module\\n         available for the current kernel (4.15.0) or it failed to\\n         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by\\n\\n           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig\\n\\n         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\\n6.1.10r138449\". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org"
```

After some hours of research i found some solution which i have tried. To sum it up, i have tried to install vbox:

```
sudo wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - \
&& wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - \
&& add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" \
&& apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms \
&& apt update -y && sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1 -y


ubuntu@ubuntu01:~# sudo vboxmanage -v
6.1.10r138449
```

```
 sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

OUTPUT:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Kernel headers are all up to date. Unfortunately i still have the same issue. Afterwards i tried to sign the kernal modules fpr EFI Secure Boot.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Descriptive common name/"

sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vboxdrv)

OUTPUT:
modinfo: ERROR: Module vboxdrv not found.
```

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0
```

Does someone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution, works for me in my VM, Am using ubuntu 18.04 and Virtualbox 6.0.14

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
```